# Jest tests are not working when run in CLI

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I'm having strange issue with testing on nestjs.

When I'm running `npm run test`, most of the tests fails. Some variables are becoming undefined, nest cannot resolve dependencies etc.
But when I'm running `ALL TESTS` from WebStorm panel, everything works fine.

https://gist.github.com/hejkerooo/5a56ee2a7d78ce41cb390d1ece648933

```
  Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TrendService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the _RootTestModule context.

      at Injector.lookupComponentInExports (node_modules/@nestjs/core/injector/injector.js:180:19)

Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at mapper (node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:25:45)

 TypeError: Cannot read property 'clear' of undefined

      17 |   beforeEach(async () => {
      18 |     jest.restoreAllMocks();
    > 19 |     await trendsRepository.clear();
         |                             ^
      20 |   });
      21 | 
      22 |   afterAll(async () => {


ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.

(node:2633) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Caught error after test environment was torn down
```

Comment: Could you provide more context about your error please ? Like the way you defined your test file, where is `TrendService` being imported and used and how you mock it in your test file. Best would be providing a repository with issue so we can reproduce and help you better

Answer (score -4):

The issue has been resolved - just used `jest.setTimeout` to `50000`, works fine.
I assume it's a temporary fix, but will dig into it.